# What are these overlapping notes with different rhythms called in Music Theory?

Tags: theory, piano, terminology, musicology, finale

On piano, when playing a long note followed by an overlapping shorter note or vice versa, what is this called? I know this is an extremely common thing in piano music, but I don't know what it's called in music theory. Also, does anyone know how to do this in finale notepad?

[image: score excerpt: dotted-quarter, eighth, quarter written above dotted half]

Comment: Two part writing/playing?

Comment: What is the overlap? Do you mean the dotted quarter, eighth, quarter is "overlapping" the dotted half note?

Comment: Are you asking about the rhythm or about the multiple "layers of melody" played at the same time in different octaves?

Answer (score 8):

They are called *voices*, and according to the Finale web site, Finale Notepad has a "layer" system for writing multiple voices.

https://usermanuals.finalemusic.com/NotePad2012Win/Content/NotePad/Multiple_Voices.htm

Here's an example picture from some other answer
[image: multiple voices]

The red circle highlights how notes overlap.

Comment: Genuinely surprised this hasn't been asked before. But several searches turned up nothing. Good, concise answer.

Comment: @Natia Welcome to Music.SE! If this answer did in fact answer your question sufficiently, I invite you to click the checkmark next to the answer to accept it. Of course, feel free to wait a bit for other answers to come in.