# Piano notes not placed as they should

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

I am reading piano music (treble clef) and there are two notes on top of each other. Yes, I know what a chord is but notes for chords are usually connected right? And the stem of the note shouldn’t be facing down because it’s on the bottom half of the treble clef. What does this weirdly written note mean?

[image]

Comment: See also: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/115002/what-are-these-overlapping-notes-with-different-rhythms-called-in-music-theory